# What is the difference between "active research" and "research"?

Tags: differences

I saw the phrase “active research” in the second-to-last paragraph of [this essay on AdmissionTable.com](http://admissiontable.com/sop-graduate-stanford-3):

> From where I stand now, I see myself engaged, in the long term, in a **career devoted to active research in microelectronics**. It is with this objective in mind that I want to pursue an M.S. at Stanford University. However, my ultimate degree objective would be a Ph.D. at Stanford University after having carefully examined the faculty and the available infrastructure.

Why did its author choose “active research” instead of just plain “research”?

I tried to find an answer on the internet, but found two terms and their definitions, *traditional research* and *action research* (not *active*). I don't think these terms have to do anything with my question.

Comment: Can you quote and link to a couple examples where you encountered the term “active research”? Context matters a lot, and the answer will depend highly on it.

Comment: A line read, "...I see myself engaged, in the long term, in a career devoted to active research in....".

Comment: Where did you read it? Can you provide a title, page, and ideally link?

Comment: Please refer to the second-last paragraph in the essay.

Comment: https://admissiontable.com/sop-graduate-stanford-3/

Comment: Please [edit] this information directly into your question.

Comment: My guess is that 'research' includes researching into what others have done, evaluating the validity of it and writing reviews in the field. 'Active research' probably means discovering and developing new things.

Comment: 'active' implies he's not interested in becoming the dead wood which infests so many tenure establishments.

Answer (score 1):

Logically speaking, *research* can be considered to include both ***active*** *research* and ***inactive*** *research*.

In other words, research projects that are currently being worked on and research projects that have been suspended.

But it's very unlikely that the anybody would say they want to work on *suspended* research, especially since that makes no real sense.

---

There are also research projects that include *practical* components and those that include only *theoretical* components.

It's likely that by using *active* as a qualifier, the research being discussed includes a practical component.

In the [referenced essay](https://admissiontable.com/sop-graduate-stanford-3/), the author says this (emphasis mine):

> I have undergone eight weeks of **practical** training in a Dept. of Electronics lab where I studied the **theoretical** and **practical** aspects of active and passive coupling of edge emitting semiconductor lasers to optical fibers.

He does distinguish between *active and passive coupling*—but *coupling* is something quite specific. It's a *topic* of research rather than a methodology.

I would argue that the most reasonable assumption is that he wants to work on research that includes practical (or hands-on) applications, rather than those that are only about theory and design.

Comment: I still don't see how you've drawn a useful distinction between the *active/inactive* dichotomy beyond the generic meanings of the terms. You've only applied them to *research*—a distinction, in my view, without a difference.

Comment: @Robusto I made a *practical* distinction. Nobody is going to write an admission essay on wanting to pursue *inactive* research. Therefore, that can't be what the author of the essay actually meant to say. What he meant to say is almost certainly that he wanted to pursue hands-on research rather than just theoretical research. The question isn't about the English language per se, it's about the use of the English language by this student in his admission essay.

Comment: Then I'm afraid that amounts to an admission that this question should be closed.